# Implementing Fullcalendar into a Wordpress page

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, fullcalendar

I'm trying to implement FullCalendar into a page on my wordpress web site using the built in page editor.

Here's the code:

```
<code>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<link href='../fullcalendar-2.0.2/fullcalendar.css' rel='stylesheet' />
<script src='../fullcalendar-2.0.2/lib/moment.min.js'></script>
<script src='../fullcalendar-2.0.2/lib/jquery.min.js'></script>
<script src='../fullcalendar-2.0.2/fullcalendar.min.js'></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {

// page is now ready, initialize the calendar...

$('#calendar').fullCalendar({
    // put your options and callbacks here
})

});
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="calendar"></div>
</body>
</html>
</code>
```

The problem I am having is that even though I am following the implementation guides closely I keep getting the error:

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <

When I click to go into the code in the console it loads nothing up and after an hour of changing small things it's completely stopped me moving forward

Comment: Try removing the `<code>`/`</code>` tags and adding a semicolon after your `fullCalendar()` method call.

Comment: that didn't work, still throwing the same error

Comment: I think the problem is that because I'm placing the code into the page, it's putting it all in the body, therefore the <head></head> portion of the code isn't placed in the actual <head></head> part of the page

Comment: That is not valid HTML, and it's actually probably the `</html>` tag that is breaking everything. Didn't realize this was in your page content. You are also using relative URLs which will break depending on your permalink structure. Try using the code in the answer below.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do this in your page's content, you should not include the `<html>`, `<head>`, etc elements. You will also need to use an absolute path to your included files so that they do not products 404 errors (likely where the error you see is coming from) - this means you need to start the URL with a `/` to point directly to the files.

Try this code, assuming that fullcalendar is in your theme under the directory `/wp-content/themes/yourtheme/fullcalendar-2.0.2/`:

```
<link href='/wp-content/themes/yourtheme/fullcalendar-2.0.2/fullcalendar.css' rel='stylesheet' />
<script src='/wp-content/themes/yourtheme/fullcalendar-2.0.2/lib/moment.min.js'></script>
<script src='/wp-content/themes/yourtheme/fullcalendar-2.0.2/lib/jquery.min.js'></script>
<script src='/wp-content/themes/yourtheme/fullcalendar-2.0.2/fullcalendar.min.js'></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    // page is now ready, initialize the calendar...
    $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
        // put your options and callbacks here
    });
});
</script>
<div id="calendar"></div>
```

Comment: sorry about late reply, I'm in the UK and I posted this quite late. I have complete run of the server so the fullcalendar folder is in the home directory of the WP backend. "localhost/mydomain/gft" in this case. I have checked the paths and they all lead to the right place.

Answer (score 0):

I have discovered that the Wordpress plugin for Fullcalendar allows for custom XML feeds. So I have managed to implement the calendar onto my page, which was the aim of this question.